# Remove inner rings from QgsGeometry polygon in QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, qgis-2

I am a QGIS python user. 
I want to iterate over the rings of a polygon to remove holes in the polygon, so:

- I need to iterate over the rings in a QgsGeometry polygon
- I need to detect the main ring of the polygon
- I need to remove every ring, which is not the main ring

How can I do that in python QGIS?

Comment: You could perhaps look into [QgsGeometry.deleteRing](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a0710a6c5b594a97f9a499d26af7a0268) which, from the description, can be called with `QgsGeometry.deleteRing(int, int partNum=0) -> bool`. I'm not an expert so hopefully others can advise.

Comment: What do you want to do if the geometry is a MultiPolygon, ie more than one outer ring - as in the case of a feature that is two islands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if geom.isMultipart() is False: # if only simple polygon, calculate only for this
        polyg = geom.asPolygon() # transform to list of points
        for ring in polyg:
            # doSomething...FILL HOLES
else: # is multipart
        multi = geom.asMultiPolygon()
        for polyg in multi:
            for ring in polyg:
                # doSomething ... FILL HOLES
```

I use this for testing and looping trought multipolygon and/or simple polygon.

Comment: I have solution, for find the first ring (main ring in geometry), in QGIS Python is it always first rinng in geom.asPolygon() list. After, I will add there full code for fill holes.

Comment: [My example for fill holes](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/MarcelGeo/gMdyg) is in function fillHoles of maptools module. In this module are more useful functions. First ring in polygon geometry is always main ring.