# PyQGIS Geometry manipulation

Tags: pyqgis, polygon

While trying to round out my answer to [Geometry Generator using polygon boundary expression only returning Exterior Ring QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/369196/geometry-generator-using-polygon-boundary-expression-only-returning-exterior-rin/370241?noredirect=1#comment604618_370241) I am trying to determine if the geometry passed into the function is a Polygon or a MultiPolygon and then to extract it's rings to pass to the zigzag drawing code.

My first attempt was to use the solution to [Remove inner rings from QgsGeometry polygon in QGIS Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159868/remove-inner-rings-from-qgsgeometry-polygon-in-qgis-python) gives me `'list' object has no attribute 'interpolatePoint'` as an error with my code looking like:

```
geoms = []
if geom.isMultipart() is False: # if only simple polygon, calculate only for this
    polyg = geom.asPolygon() # transform to list of points
    for ring in polyg:
        geoms.append(ring)
else: # is multipart
    multi = geom.asMultiPolygon()
    for polyg in multi:
        for ring in polyg:
            geoms.append(ring)
# interpolate points on linestring
for gx in geoms:
    points2d = [(lambda g: (g.x(), g.y()))(gx.interpolatePoint(d)) for d in distances]
    vertices = gx.points()
```

So one of the `asX` methods returned an empty list instead of a Polygon, I think?

So next I tried to go from basics with:

```
geoms = []

# assume it is a polygon
if geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.Polygon:
    poly = geom.asPolygon()
    geoms.append(poly.exteriorRing())
else:
    geoms.append(geom.boundary())
```

Which gives the same error message when applied to polygon features.
So then I tried:

```
geoms = []

geoms.append(geom.exteriorRing())    
for i in range(0,geom.getNumInteriorRings()):
    geoms.append(geom.getInteriorRingN(i))
```

But it says, `Eval Error: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'exteriorRing'` so I thought it needed changing to a polygon.
Finally, I tried:

geoms = []

```
poly = geom.asPolygon()
geoms.append(poly.exteriorRing())    
for i in range(0,poly.getNumInteriorRings()):
    geoms.append(poly.getInteriorRingN(i))
```

But that just says `'list' object has no attribute 'exteriorRing'`
My test features are:

```
Polygon ((513366.96000000002095476 102956.35000000000582077, 513355.33000000001629815 102954.64999999999417923, 513356.32000000000698492 102947.89999999999417923, 513367.95000000001164153 102949.60000000000582077, 513366.96000000002095476 102956.35000000000582077))
Polygon ((513392.47999999998137355 102973.47999999999592546, 513401.75 102916.32000000000698492, 513424.30999999999767169 102919.85000000000582077, 513415.40000000002328306 102977.08000000000174623, 513392.47999999998137355 102973.47999999999592546),(513408.89000000001396984 102967.58999999999650754, 513415.45000000001164153 102926.5, 513407.88000000000465661 102925.28999999999359716, 513401.32000000000698492 102966.38000000000465661, 513408.89000000001396984 102967.58999999999650754))
```

So (currently) there is no problem with a multipolygon or anything complicated.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't really get the question here. Do you need a list of rings (as line strings) from an input geometry, regardless of if it is multi/single-part and if it has interior rings or not? If so, I have a function for that.

Comment: that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function (adapted from [here](https://github.com/SwissTierrasColombia/Asistente-LADM-COL/blob/master/asistente_ladm_col/lib/geometry.py#L53)) receives a polygon geometry and gives you a `QgsMultiLineString` with all polygon rings. It takes into account single and multi-parts.

```
def get_polygon_rings_as_lines(polygon):    
    # Input polygon can be multi or single part
    # and could have interior rings
    
    def get_rings_from_polygon_part(part_polygon):
        part_rings = list()
        part_rings.append(part_polygon.exteriorRing().clone())
        for i in range(part_polygon.numInteriorRings()):
            part_rings.append(part_polygon.interiorRing(i).clone())

        return part_rings
    
    abs_polygon = polygon.get()
    ring_list = list()
    
    if polygon.isMultipart():
        for part in range(abs_polygon.numGeometries()):
            ring_list.extend(get_rings_from_polygon_part(abs_polygon.geometryN(part)))
    else:
        ring_list.extend(get_rings_from_polygon_part(abs_polygon))
    
    rings = QgsMultiLineString()
    for ring in ring_list:
        rings.addGeometry(ring)
    
    return rings
```

---

Note that when dealing with PyQGIS geometries, sometimes you might need the `QgsGeometry` (which is defined as a container in [the docs](https://api.qgis.org/master/classQgsGeometry.html#details)) and sometimes you might need the real geometry primitive (`QgsAbstractGeometry`).

Comment: Thanks German and Ian. I was getting some errors in the function so I added these to the top to try to fix them. from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_polygon_rings_as_lines(polygon, feature, parent):       And now I don't get an error but It returns nothing in the preview where I would expect to see <Geometry: Multilinestring>. And also nothing on the screen

Comment: Also in my research I came across this post by Nyall Dawson. That makes it seem like it should be easier in QGIS >3.6. https://nyalldawson.net/tag/pyqgis/  But I know nothing about python so am lost.